# A lambda with a template parameter list using C++20 requires clauses is not usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts

In the template function `f`, I define a lambda with a template parameter list which can use `if constexpr` to detect whether the type `U` is a `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
  auto g = []<typename U>(U u) {
    if constexpr (requires { std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>; }) {
      if constexpr (std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>) {
        // deal with std::vector<U::value_type>
      }
    }
    else {
      // deal with other type
    }
  };
  g(t);
}
```

But when I call the `f` in the `main` function:

```
int main()
{
  f(std::vector<int>{});
}
```

[**The GCC-10 compiler occurs an error saying that:**](https://godbolt.org/z/s4n1fe)

```
<source>:19:23:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/concepts:57:15:   required for the satisfaction of '__same_as<_Tp, _Up>' [with _Tp = U; _Up = std::vector<typename U::value_type, std::allocator<typename U::value_type> >]
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/concepts:57:32: error: the value of 'std::is_same_v<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type, std::allocator<typename U::value_type> > >' is not usable in a constant expression
   57 |       concept __same_as = std::is_same_v<_Tp, _Up>;
      |                           ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/concepts:44,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:3182:25: note: 'std::is_same_v<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type, std::allocator<typename U::value_type> > >' used in its own initializer
 3182 |   inline constexpr bool is_same_v = _GLIBCXX_BUILTIN_IS_SAME_AS(_Tp, _Up);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~
```

This seems weird to me since the type `U` can be deduced in the compiler time. **Is this a bug for GCC-10? or there some issue in the above code?**

Weirder, when  I change the origin requires clauses into **nested requirements**:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
  auto g = []<typename U>(U u) {
    if constexpr (requires { requires std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>; }) {
      // deal with std::vector<U::value_type>
    }
    else {
      // deal with other type
    }
  };
  g(t);
}
```

The GCC occurs an **internal compiler error**:

```
<source>:19:23:   required from here
<source>:7:39: internal compiler error: in dependent_type_p, at cp/pt.c:26400
    7 |     if constexpr (requires { requires std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>; }) {
      |                              ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

and when I change the template function `f` into a non-template function:

```
void f(std::vector<int> t) {
  auto g = []<typename U>(U u) {
    if constexpr (requires { requires std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>; }) {
      // deal with std::vector<U::value_type>
    }
    else {
      // deal with other type
    }
  };
  g(t);
}
```

It will compile correctly, [**and all three examples do compile with Clang**](https://godbolt.org/z/6c3PGz).

Comment: It's quite possible this is a bug, which isn't too uncommon with newly implemented functionality. I'd recommend giving their bug tracker a search to see if anything similar is in there.l

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but you're using `same_as` incorrectly. Currently the truthfullness of the concept is discarded, so you only check for *validity* of the expression (i.e. validitity of `typename U::value_type`). If `typename U::value_type` is known to always be valid, you can simply write `if constexpr (std::same_as<...>)` (this compiles). If not, then `if constexpr (requires{requires std::same_as<...>;})` (should compile, but causes internal compiler error on GCC). All three examples do compile with Clang, even when using GCC's libstdc++.

Comment: How can U the same as U::value_type?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right, I mess up with the `same_as`. If I understand correctly, the right constraint should be `requires { typename U::value_type; requires std::same_as<U, std::vector<typename U::value_type>>; }`?

Comment: I don't think you need to separately check `typename U::value_type;`. If the compiler sees that it's invalid while checking `std::same_as<...>`, the whole `requires{...}` will automatically return false.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh I see, that is my second example. thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems there are many bugs :-) This compiles for gcc10.1+10.2+clang. But gcc10.1 compiles to wrong code! https://godbolt.org/z/5Tf6hz

Comment: @Klaus but gcc10.2 [still got internal compiler error for nested requires.](https://godbolt.org/z/nvMqdM)

Comment: @康桓瑋: So please write a bug report! This helps a lot to get a an improved compiler early!

Comment: Weird this is my gcc 10.2 build locally doesn't ICE. Now I'm wondering what I did to build the thing...

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes, I mean your exact example.

Comment: With Gcc10.1 requires expression in the body of generic lambda declared in function template always return true. I filled a bug report and it was fixed in few days https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95020. This new bug is a follow up of this Gcc10.1 bug, it might report help to add a link in the bug report